# Multiple inheritance of class broken up into modules

Tags: python, object-oriented, design-patterns, inheritance

I have a class `Main` that uses `fn(cls, ...)` methods from several modules; they're used exclusively by `Main`. Each module is 500-1000 lines long (without docstrings); the idea is to "break up" various `Main` methods to ease debugging and readability, instead of packing them all into one class and make a 9000+ lines file.

Everything functions properly. However, a core asset is sacrificed: *introspection*; `help(Main.method)`, or even `Main.method()` are no longer an option. The goal is thus as follows: keep methods in separate files, but have them behave just like regular class methods.

---

**My approach**: 'pack' module methods into classes, then module classes into a 'unifier' class, then inherit the unifier in `Main`. Code below. Points to note:

- No overriding issues; `Module` classes only hold methods, their `__init__` is as minimal as shown
- No attributes, per above, and thus same for `Unifier`
- No duplicate attributes / methods; all methods are uniquely named (and no attrs to duplicate)

---

**Question**: any caveats to note? What can be done better? Some particular concerns are:

1. Is `pickle.dump`, `.load` affected? I pickle only non-method `Main` attributes.
2. Is a dynamic `to_unify` reliable? I suppose 'it depends' on how all involved classes change along.
3. Any metaclass intricacies from the inheritance scheme?

---

**Code**: [live demo](https://repl.it/repls/StrongLeafyWireframe)

```py
# module_a.py
class ModuleA():
    def __init__(self):
        super(ModuleA, self).__init__()

    def woof(self):
        """I'm a dog"""
        self.do_woofing()  # dependency on ModuleB

    def do_dooting(self):
        print("DOOT")
```

```py
# module_b.py
class ModuleB():
    def __init__(self):
        super(ModuleB, self).__init__()

    def doot(self):
        """I'm a skeleton"""
        self.do_dooting()  # dependency on ModuleA

    def do_woofing(self):
        print("WOOF")
```

```py
# main_module.py
from module_a import ModuleA
from module_b import ModuleB

to_unify = ModuleA, ModuleB  # can add modules later

class Unifier(*to_unify):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Unifier, self).__init__()

class Main(Unifier):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        # ...
```

```py
# main.py
from main_module import Main

m = Main()
m.woof()
m.doot()
help(m.doot)
```

```
WOOF
DOOT
Help on method doot in module module_b:

doot() method of main_module.Main instance
    I'm a skeleton
```

Comment: I think this is symptom of other design problem ("god class").  If you have 9000+ lines worth of methods on one class definition then probably that class has too many responsibilities.

Comment: @wim Agreed this is typically true, but it's the main class within a deep learning framework, where official implementations have similar lengths (unavoidably). Also a large fraction of these lines would be documentation - actual code's 5-6k.

Comment: (`actual code's 5-6k [of] 9000+ lines` That is not what I would consider a *large fraction* with "javadoc-style documentation" - with docstrings (introspectable) and the odd comment, it's a start.)

Comment: If you want a review here, please a) be sure you are willing and in a position to put code from your project [under Creative Commons](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/licensing) and b) present actual code from your project.

Comment: Correction, ~2500 lines of code in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is accomplished more elegantly and minimally by:

1. Fetching methods from relevant modules
2. Assigning these methods to the class, programmatically

We can further ensure that methods are intended for the class by checking whether `self` is in the input signature, and can omit specific methods by name. Below accomplishes this:

```py
from inspect impport getfullargspec
from package_a import module_1a, module_2a
import package_b.module_1b

class Unifier():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

args = lambda x: getfullargspec(x).args
modules = (module_1a, module_2a, module_1b)  # extendable
to_exclude = ['_method_to_omit']

for module in modules:
    mm = get_module_methods(module)
    for name, method in mm.items():
        if name in to_exclude or 'self' not in args(method):
            continue
        setattr(Unifier, name, method)
```

Now `Main`, after inheriting `Unifier`, will have all `fn(self, ...)` methods from `module_1a, module_2a, module_1b` (except `def _method_to_omit`).

- `get_module_methods` [source](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/242109/get-methods-in-module-python/#answer-242148)
- Method class assignment ideas derived from [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61739682/bound-method-class-fn-vs-bound-method-fn)

Answer (score 0):

Hi  OverLordGoldDragon,

Why don't you define your methods as functions in your submodules and attach them to your main class afterwards?

```py
# module_a.py

def woof(self):
    """I'm a dog"""
    self.do_woofing() 

def do_dooting(self):
    print("DOOT")
```

```py
# module_b.py

def doot(self):
    """I'm a skeleton"""
    self.do_dooting()

def do_woofing(self):
    print("WOOF")
```

```py
import module_a, module_b       # I know some people won't like this form of import

class Main:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do whatever you need to do to initialize your instance
        pass

    woof = module_a.woof
    do_dooting = module_a.do_dooting
    doot = module_b.doot
    do_woofing = module_b.do_woofing
```

```py
# main.py
from main_module import Main

m = Main()
m.woof()
m.doot()
help(m.doot)
```

I want to highlight the fact that `help()` is supposed to be used at the interactive prompt not in a script.

Comment: This indeed works, though I had a more complete answer planned before you posted, just couldn't post earlier