# Get methods in module, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Goal: extract methods/functions *defined in module*. This excludes:

1. Imports
2. Lambda methods
3. Magic methods
4. Builtin methods
5. Class methods
6. Classes
7. Non-original definitions (i.e. function assignments, `alt_name = orig_fn`)

My approach + test below. Any room for improvement, or false positives/negatives? (In particular I wonder if we can get away without typechecks, e.g. `isinstance(method, types.LambdaType)`)

---

**Code**: [live demo](https://repl.it/repls/LittleFantasticAssemblylanguage)

```py
import utils

def get_module_methods(module):
    def is_module_function(obj):
        return ('<function' in str(obj) and
                module.__name__ in getattr(obj, '__module__', ''))

    def not_lambda(obj):
        return not ('<lambda>' in getattr(obj, '__qualname__', ''))

    def not_magic(obj):
        s = getattr(obj, '__name__', '').split('__')
        return (len(s) < 2) or not (s[0] == s[-1] == '')

    def not_duplicate(name, obj):
        return name == getattr(obj, '__name__', '')

    def cond(name, obj):
        return (is_module_function(obj) and not_lambda(obj) and
                not_magic(obj) and not_duplicate(name, obj))

    objects = {name: getattr(module, name) for name in dir(module)}
    m_methods = {}

    for name, obj in objects.items():
        if cond(name, obj):
            m_methods[name] = obj
    return m_methods

mm = get_module_methods(utils)
_ = [print(k, '--', v) for k, v in mm.items()]
```

---

**Test**:

```py
# utils.py
import random
import numpy as np
from inspect import getsource


def fn1(a, b=5):
  print("wrong animal", a, b)

class Dog():
  meow = fn1
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def bark(self):
    print("WOOF")

d = Dog()
barker = d.bark
mewoer = d.meow
A = 5
arr = np.random.randn(100, 100)

def __getattr__(name):
  return getattr(random, name, None)

magic = __getattr__
duplicate = fn1
_builtin = str
lambd = lambda: 1
```

```py
# main.py
import utils

# def get_module_methods(): ...

mm = get_module_methods(utils)
_ = [print(k, '--', v) for k, v in mm.items()]
```

```py
fn1 -- <function fn1 at 0x7f00a7eb2820>
```

---

**Edit**: additional test case for a lambda surrogate:

```py
import functools

def not_lambda():
    return 1
functools.wraps(lambda i: i)(not_lambda).__name__
```

Code in question and answer catch `not_lambda` as a `lambda` - false positive.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @Peilonrayz for the original answer, but I figure it's worth including a more complete version of the working function:

```py
from types import LambdaType

def get_module_methods(module):
    output = {}
    for name in dir(module):
        obj = getattr(module, name)
        obj_name = getattr(obj, '__name__', '')
        if ((str(obj).startswith('<function')
             and isinstance(obj, LambdaType)) # is a function
            and module.__name__ == getattr(obj, '__module__', '')  # same module
            and name in str(getattr(obj, '__code__', ''))  # not a duplicate
            and "__%s__" % obj_name.strip('__') != obj_name  # not a magic method
            and '<lambda>' not in str(getattr(obj, '__code__'))  # not a lambda
        ):
            output[name] = obj
    return output
```

Lambda detection taken from [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56451020/is-there-any-way-to-tell-if-a-function-object-was-a-lambda-or-a-def). Note that we can omit the `isinstance(obj, LambdaType)` typecheck, but with caveats:

- `str(obj).startswith('<function')` is insufficient to tell whether `obj` is a function, since we can define a class whose `__str__` returns `'<function'` (as pointed by Peilonrayz). However, `__str__` is effective on a class *instance*, which fails the `# not a duplicate` check - so we can "luck out". This is unlikely in practice, but here's where a typecheck may be necessary:

```py
class Dog():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__name__ = 'd'
d = Dog()
```

---

**Edit**: changed `# not a duplicate` check, which would falsely exclude `not_lambda`.

Answer (score 3):

#### pyclbr

The standard library includes the `pyclbr` module, which provides functions for building a module browser.  `pyclbr.readmodule_ex()` returns a tree of nested dicts with the functions (`def`statements) and classes (`class` statements) in a module.  So you just need to check the top level dict for items of class `pyclbr.Function`.

Note that `readmodule_ex` takes the name of the module (a str), not the actual module.

Just tested this, and it prints out imported functions and dunder functions as well, so those need to be filtered out.

```
import pyclbr

module = 'tutils'

for k,v in pyclbr.readmodule_ex(module).items():
    if (    isinstance(v, pyclbr.Function) 
        and v.module==module
        and not v.name.startswith('__')):
        print(f"{v.name} -- {v.file} at {v.lineno}")
```

Comment: Looks plausible, but the code given as-is fails the test case in the question (nothing is printed).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon, it printed out too much when I ran it, so I had to add tests for imported functions and dunder functions.  Note, the source file for the module has to be on the search path so `pyclbr` can find it.

Comment: This does work, but it's more of an 'alternative' than 'code review' - also worth mentioning this [docs'](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pyclbr.html) note: _"information is extracted from the Python source code rather than by importing the module, so this module is safe to use with untrusted code"_ - which is an advantage over existing answers.

Answer (score 2):

- Not a fan of all these redundant functions.
- Use equality for equality and `in` for in.

  - `'<function' in str(obj)` -> `str(obj).startswith('<function')`
  - `module.__name__ in ...` -> `module.__name__ == ...`
  - `not ('<lambda>' in ...)` -> `'<lambda>' not in ...` -> `'<lambda>' != ...`

  Lets play a game of what if:

  - What if `foo.fn` is copied to `foo.bar.fn`.
  - What if someone built a function from a lambda so they changed the name to `fn_from_<lambda>`.

  Yeah, let's stick to using `==` for equals.
- Why is there a dictionary comprehension when the for after it consumes it?

  This is just a waste of memory.
- like with the dictionary compression this is a waste of memory. Additionally it's normally easier to work from a plain for as you can use assignments.

  ```py
  _ = [print(k, '--', v) for k, v in mm.items()]
  ```

```py
import utils


def get_module_methods(module):
    output = {}
    for name in dir(module):
        obj = getattr(module, name)
        obj_name = getattr(obj, '__name__', '')
        if (str(obj).startswith('<function')  # Is function
            and '<lambda>' != obj_name  # Not a lambda
            and module.__name__ == getattr(obj, '__module__', '')  # Same module
            and name == obj_name
            and not (  # Dunder
                obj_name.startswith('__')
                and obj_name.endswith('__')
                and len(obj_name) >= 5
            )
        ):
            output[name] = obj
    return output


mm = get_module_methods(utils)
for k, v in mm.items():
    print(k, '--', v)
```

Lets play another game of what if:

- What if I have a class that's `__str__` returns `'<function...'`?
- What if someone built a function from a lambda so changed the `__name__`?

  ```py
  import functools
  functools.wraps(lambda i: i)(...).__name__
  ```

> In particular I wonder if we can get away without typechecks

No.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. Valid loopholes in last two bullets, but the answer doesn't address them; I suppose a typecheck addresses the first, but how would one reliably identify a lambda?

Comment: To address some points: (1) I don't see the problem with "`foo.fn` is copied to `foo.bar.fn`"; (2) `'<lambda>' != ...` can't tell how this is better than `'<lambda>' not in`; (3) "waste of memory" - it's for readability, and their memory use is negligible (and garbage-collected);  (4) `# Same module` not necessarily; if in PYTHONPATH, a package level can be bypassed, e.g. `from a import b` -> `import b`, but this has its own problems, and I agree with your preference for `==` here; still worth a mention.

Comment: The answer to your first question is in _your question_. (1) It's a bug (2) Please read the bullet point again. `fn_from_<lambda>` is _not_ a lambda. (3) Yeah, that's not more readable.

Comment: (2) I know, so _how do we tell_ if it isn't? Your code thinks it is, just like mine.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I have already answered that off-topic question.

Comment: No, you haven't - and your answer stands as incomplete by your own assessment. Maybe I'll still 'accept' it as a net-positive, but the shortcomings should be supposedly easy to correct.

Comment: To clarify, I see how `'<lambda> != `  works - my question concerns not the running point "(2)", but "how to not filter a trojan horse" (e.g. functools's). Dedicated a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61758005/how-to-detect-a-lambda-in-python).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Please stop harassing me.

Comment: I've done nothing to harass you.